# CompileAssemblyFromSource & Global Keyboard Hook Not Working Together

Tags: c#

So I have a program that compiles a program using a source from a string.
Everything works fine. (C#)

On my main application, I have a global keyboard hook to capture keystrokes (im using it to do an action whilst a key is pressed) and it works okay.

But as I reference the keyboard hook library I am using into my Compiler options (references), I cant get it to work within that programmatically compiled program.
Its just not picking up my keystrokes at all.

No compilation errors.
im using
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
To reference the .cs file for the global keyboard hook class I am using.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: EDIT: It is a console application and I believe something is not working okay with that fact... any idea for global keyboard hooks on console applications?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved!
With GetAsyncKeyState:

```
[DllImport(""user32"", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
```